# Angular5 jQuery function evaluating as undefined but not in devTools

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular5

I'm having a kind of strange problem with Angular5 when using a jQuery function, which in my case, it's the [select2 library](https://select2.org/)

The fact is that I'm using it inside a dynamically rendered component, with its code:

#### Current code status

```
@ViewChild('mainCountry') mainCountrySelect: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('compareCountry') compareCountrySelect: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const mainSelectNE = this.mainCountrySelect.nativeElement;
    const mainSelectID = mainSelectNE.getAttribute('id');

    const compareSelectNE = this.compareCountrySelect.nativeElement;
    const compareSelectID = compareSelectNE.getAttribute('id');

    console.log(
        'Main ID: ' + mainSelectID,
        'Main EL: ', $(mainSelectNE),
        'Compare ID: ' + compareSelectID,
        'Compare EL: ', $(compareSelectNE)
    );

    (<any>$(mainSelectNE)).select2(defaultSelect2Options);
    (<any>$(compareSelectNE)).select2(defaultSelect2Options);
}
```

#### And this is what I've tried so far

Apart from using `ngAfterContentInit` hook (exactly the same as `ngAfterViewInit`, I've tried polling jQuery to check if function exists, like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const mainSelectNE = this.mainCountrySelect.nativeElement;
    const mainSelectID = mainSelectNE.getAttribute('id');

    const compareSelectNE = this.compareCountrySelect.nativeElement;
    const compareSelectID = compareSelectNE.getAttribute('id');

    console.log(
        'Main ID: ' + mainSelectID,
        'Main EL: ', $(mainSelectNE),
        'Compare ID: ' + compareSelectID,
        'Compare EL: ', $(compareSelectNE)
    );

    const funcInterval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log((<any>$.fn).select2);
    },500);

    /*
    (<any>$(mainSelectNE)).select2(defaultSelect2Options);
    (<any>$(compareSelectNE)).select2(defaultSelect2Options);
    */
}
```

Which is always returning `undefined`.

I've tried using `$(document).ready()`, but it still not working.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const mainSelectNE = this.mainCountrySelect.nativeElement;
    const mainSelectID = mainSelectNE.getAttribute('id');

    const compareSelectNE = this.compareCountrySelect.nativeElement;
    const compareSelectID = compareSelectNE.getAttribute('id');

    console.log(
        'Main ID: ' + mainSelectID,
        'Main EL: ', $(mainSelectNE),
        'Compare ID: ' + compareSelectID,
        'Compare EL: ', $(compareSelectNE)
    );

    // same as $(document).ready()
    $(() => {
        (<any>$(mainSelectNE)).select2(defaultSelect2Options);
        (<any>$(compareSelectNE)).select2(defaultSelect2Options);
    });
}
```

The strange part is that if I try accessing it on Google Chrome's dev console, it works. `$.fn.select2` outputs it, and `$('#' + mainSelectID).select2()` works aswell (still in devTools). And all the app's scripts are being loaded inside `scripts.bundle.js`, which is loaded

Comment: How are you adding the jquery library to the application?

Comment: @JeanPaulA. it gets bundled with gulp inside `vendors.bundle.js`

Comment: @JeanPaulA. just to point it out, neither including it into `angular-cli.json`solved the issue

Comment: Alas, that's what i was going to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at code, and after many other tries, I've solved the issue.
My `ScriptsLoaderService`(which I didn't post because it isn't relevant) was loading all the bundled scripts inside `scripts.bundle.js`, creating jQuery instance and all the other libs.

Inside dynamically created component i was using jQuery within all imports like this:

`import $ = require('jquery')`

That was creating another instance of jQuery, for the component scope.
And obviously it didn't have all the libs which I needed (and that's why Chrome DevTools had them)

I've solved it just by replacing the code above with this one

`declare var jQuery`

Which references to global element.
I knew that, but I didn't thought it was my problem